# React-Native - undefined is not an object (“evaluating _react3.default.PropTypes.shape”)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

ERROR:

```
undefined is not an object (“evaluating _react3.default.PropTypes.shape”)
...
<unknown>
App.js 15
...
```

Refer:
http://rationalappdev.com/react-native-list-app-complete-how-to-guide/

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

const RouteMapper = (route, navigationOperations, onComponentRef) => {
  if (route.name === 'list') {
    return (
      // TODO: Add List component
      <Text>The list is going to be here</Text>
    );
  } else if (route.name === 'movie') {
    // TODO: Add Movie component for a movie detail screen
  }
};

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationExperimental.Navigator
        // Default to list route
        initialRoute={{name: 'list'}}
        // Use FloatFromBottom transition between screens
        configureScene={(route, routeStack) => NavigationExperimental.Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom}
        // Pass a route mapper functions
        renderScene={RouteMapper}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "0.49.3",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-beta.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

**UPDATE**

still not working after install `prop-types`

[image]

Comment: try `npm install --save-dev prop-types`

Comment: you should repost that comment as an answer as it is the answer to his question

Answer (score 1):

PropTypes has been moved out of react and into it's own component:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types

According to the README, they recommend adding **prop-types** to your **dependencies** block in **package.json**

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

Then to use it:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
var PropTypes = require('prop-types'); // ES5 with npm
```